# Heating milk in yogurt-making

Tags: yogurt, reheating, heat, evaporated-milk

I'd like to make yogurt with non-fat dried milk enriched with canned (full-fat) evaporated milk.  Since both these products have already been heated in the manufacture, do I need to heat/cool the mixture (as I would fresh milk) before adding the starter culture?

Comment: What result do you expect by adding evaporated milk?

Comment: I have made very good yogurt with non-fat dried milk that does not need to be heated and cooled --  a process that would add a great deal of additional prep time. But some people prefer their yogurt made with whole or partially de-fatted milk.  I'm not sure the difference in flavor and texture, but I didn't want a lot of time in heating and cooling if it were not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, go with your gut. It is possible that you see a very slight advantage, or that you don't have any at all, so do as you feel better.

The denaturing of proteins has already been done in both the canned and dried milks, so you don't need to heat up for that part. What you can win is a bit on the contamination front. Making yogurt is about creating an ecosystem, and to give your preferred culture the best start in life, you are trying to keep the mixture as sterile as possible. The combination of canned milk, milk powder and water shouldn't have any more bacteria and yeasts than anything else in your kitchen, and heated milk gets re-contaminated during cooling, so if you can get any edge, it will be small. But if you want to shoot for it, there is no harm in that. Especially if you are reinoculating from the old batch a lot, this might reduce the time until you have to refresh your culture.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that commercial dehydration was done at lower temperatures than those used at home, made possible by processing in a partial vacuum. I didn't know whether those lower temps were sufficient to denature the proteins.